# Is there any scenario where programmer use IL as their primary language for writing code

Tags: .net, il

Most of the developer use one of the core .NET language ( Like c#, vb.net, c++/cli etc) to create their applications/developers. I was just wondering if any one would use Intermediate Language (IL) as their primary language for their day to day job as programmer.

Comment: I think these days only compilers write IL [often]

Comment: this would probably be better on http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: *Nobody* makes a living writing IL.  If ever there was somebody, he got quickly outsourced to somebody with a compiler.

Comment: Possibly those who do IL weaving, such as writers of AOP frameworks and some O/RMs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't imagine a situation where you would need to. Assuming the .NET compilers are decent, it would be wise (and more efficient in terms of time spent coding) to leave IL-level optimizations to the compiler, rather than trusting yourself to do them.

In the time required to write some code in IL, you could do 10x the work in C# in the same time, and the .NET compiler would likely do a better job than we would of optimizing it too.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no reason for programming in IL unless you are forced to.

IL is not invented as a programming language. It is (as the name implies) an Intermediate Language -- one that is generated as output from a high-level language and then later compiled into machine code, typically in runtime by a JIT-compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Although I agree with the other answers, I would like to add that there are a few cases where it can be useful to write IL:

- dynamic code generation (using `Reflection.Emit`), although it's typically done for a very short piece of IL code
- If you need to do something that is supported by the CLR but not by your usual langage

Comment: Can you give any example for your item 2?

Comment: @palm snow, for instance indexed properties are not supported in C#, but they are supported in IL (and in VB.NET too). IL also supports methods that return a reference to a variable (in C# they can only return a value). Generic constraints for Delegate and Enum are another example.